# Python, Hadoop : IOError: File does not exist, but the file is present in the path

Tags: python, hadoop

I am writing a map reduce in hadoop using python and pandas. In my reducer, i am calling a function and am reading a file in it. But the reducer gives the below error -

```
IOError: File /path/subset_clean.tsv does not exist
```

Below is the code i used -

```
file_loc='path/subset_clean.tsv'
def func(list_app):
  headers=pd.read_csv(file_loc, sep='\t', low_memory=False,nrows=1)
  headers_name=list(headers)
  subset=pd.DataFrame(list_app,columns=headers_name)
  .
  .
  return;

reducer code
 call func(list_app)
```

list_app is the list passed on from the reducer to the function.

But when i don't read the file, and define the variable as below, it works absolutely fine - 
    headers_name=('col1','col2',    'col3')

I'm unable to get around this error.

**EDIT** - 
when i run the previous code with the relative path using the below command, it works perfectly fine -

```
cat sample_reduce_33016_n.tsv|python mapper_try.py|sort|python reducer_new_v1.py>sample_red_reslt.tsv
```

Comment: Your error message mentions an absolute path, while in your code you have a relative path...

Comment: Your path is probably wrong. Please, make the difference between a *relative* path and an *absolute* path.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. But i am unable to understand the difference in the functioning of a relative and an absolute path. The path though i am sure is right.

Comment: Please see the edit on the above post. The functioning of the code by running it in python validates the path's correctness.

Comment: i tried the same with absolute reference as well, but still it says the same. @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: "But i am unable to understand the difference in the functioning of a relative and an absolute path" : a relative path (like "foo/bar/baaztxt") will be resolved against the "current working directory" (the directory you are in when running the script - NOT the directory the script lives in). An absolute path is, well, absolute - there's nothing to resolve, so it will be the same whatever the current working directory.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. @AkshatAgrawal have you got any solution?